# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in Cent os

Tags: php, mysql, centos

When I run the  following script in my server : http://192.163.227.245/~ealthte6/e_marps/emarps/database/db_connect.php
I gives me a blank page and generates the  following error in my error_log file :

```
[11-Feb-2015 23:30:30 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/ealthte6/public_html/e_marps/emarps/database/db_connect.php on line 6
```

I have checked my php.ini file : http://192.163.227.245/~ealthte6/info.php 
I have mysql enabled I just don't understand why I keep getting this error. Please can you advise ? 
Below is my connection script :

```
<?php
$db_connection = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'marps_user';
$db_passwd = '123456';
$db_name = 'marps_db';
$link = mysql_connect($db_connection,$db_user , $db_passwd);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: I think your server wants to communicate with you and tell you to not use `mysql_*` API. I think your server wants that you use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (Like ever person likes different coffee, your server just doesn't like mysql_*, like many other servers)

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions ! use PDO / MySQLi instead. Did you ever read PHP documentation ?

Comment: check that you have un-commented the extension (pref mysqli_) in your config file

Comment: Use phpinfo() to check weather it is enabled or not. Please don't use mysql_* functions it is deprecated

Comment: But MySQLi  is not configured on the  server, Do I have to reconfigure it again?

Comment: I closed against a duplicate as the information in your question looks outdated. The links aren't working any longer. Please put the information into the question, not just link them (as they tend to go away). If you have any updates, please edit the question. If you found the solution, please leave an answer below or with the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the mysql is connected with php... You can find it thru below code

create a php page as info.php with code
phpinfo();

And check whether mysql is configured while making/installing the php.